# Access licensed object records from Partner Community

Tags: apex, community, partner-communities, experience-cloud

We are planning to expose some of our org data to a partner Community using Experince Cloud. However the data which we want to expose is licensed and can only be viewed with users having that license.

We want the users from the external Partner community to able to view the licensed data without having to provide them with licenses, as it is a bit expensive. So, I need some suggestions on how I can overcome this.

Comment: When you say "Licensed data", can you be more specific? Do you mean Opportunities, Contracts or something similar?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) then [edit] your question to explain what you've tried and where you are stuck (or to demonstrate that you've researched this and drawn a blank). It would be sensible also to make it clear whether these records are for objects from a standard Salesforce product or from an App Exchange app.

Comment: If you're referring to an AppExchange installed package's licensing, then you'll have to check with the app vendor.